# Limit of chi square distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, sampling, chi-squared

Question in my exercise is written as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-t}{2}}t^{\frac{n}{2}-1}dt\bigg)$$ equals :

$(A)=.5$

$(B)=0$

$(C)=.0228$

$(D)=.1587$

As sample size increase chi square approaches normal distribution.(I am not sure if i wrote this statement correct so please correct me and give me little explanation on that). Using this fact i calculated $P(X>n-\sqrt{2n}) = \Phi(-1) = .1587$. Did i do everything correct using this intuition ?

Comment: Yes sorry let me edit that out.And what is the explanation i am seeking as sample size grow. Could you please tell me ?

Comment: Why is it $P(X>n-\sqrt{2n}) \approx \Phi(-1)$ and not $P(X>n-\sqrt{2n}) \approx 1- \Phi(-1) = \Phi(1)$ ?

Comment: ohh yes i did  a mistake. It should be $\Phi(1)$

Comment: An explanation is the application of the central limit theorem to random variables (squares of standard normal random variables) with mean $1$ and variance $2$

Comment: @Henry Please elaborate to me i didn't get thing out of your last statement. I know central limit theorem but what should be the right approach to use it here?

Comment: A chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of the sum of the squares of $n$ independent standard normal random variables.  The square of one standard normal random variable has mean $1$ and variance $2$, so if $Y_n$ is average of $n$ of them then the central limit theorem says $\sqrt n\left(\frac{Y_n-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ converges in distribution to a standard normal as $n$ increases.  You are considering the sum rather than the average, i.e. $X_n=nY_n$, so can say $\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal as $n$ increases

Comment: ohh yes so in our case according CLT mean is $n$ and variance is $\frac{2n}{n}$ right ? That will cancel out $n$.

Comment: $P(\frac{X-n}{2}>\frac{n-n-\sqrt{2n}}{2})$ gives me area to one side that is $.5$ right?

Comment: @Henry tell me please there is down one answer too. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$? There is no $x$ in the term.

Comment: @robjohn Oh yess n sorry so many mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one mistake in your main equation: $x$ should be $n.$
Perhaps also, in view of @Henry's Comment and my explanation below, the lower limit of the integral was meant to be $n + \sqrt{2n}.$

As it stands, the expression of which you are taking the limit amounts to $P_n = 1- F_n(n-\sqrt{2n}),$ or $$P_n = P\left[X_n > E(X_n) - SD(X_n)\right],$$ where $X_n \sim \mathsf{Chisq(n)}.$

The probability that $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ has 
$$P\left[Z > E(Z) - SD(Z)\right] = P(Z > -1) = 1 - P(Z \le -1) = P(Z \le 1)
= 0.8413,$$
where the last step is by symmetry. In R statistical software, where
`pnorm` (without 2nd and 3rd arguments) is $\Phi(\cdot),$ one obtains:

```
1 - pnorm(-1)
## 0.8413447
pnorm(1)
## 0.8413447
```

Thus according to the CLT (and the continuity of the CDF), $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P_n = 0.8413.$ A simple
computation in R, where `pchisq` denotes a CDF, indicates the speed of this convergence:

```
n = c(1:10, 25, 30, 50, 75, 100, 500, 1000)
p = 1 - pchisq(n-sqrt(2*n), n)

cbind(n, p)             # 17 x 2 matrix brackets [] show row indexes                
         n         p
 [1,]    1 1.0000000
 [2,]    2 1.0000000
 [3,]    3 0.9076624
 [4,]    4 0.8827564
 [5,]    5 0.8711126
 [6,]    6 0.8644286
 [7,]    7 0.8601196
 [8,]    8 0.8571235
 [9,]    9 0.8549262
[10,]   10 0.8532494
[11,]   25 0.8453927
[12,]   30 0.8446442
[13,]   50 0.8432274
[14,]   75 0.8425623
[15,]  100 0.8422420
[16,]  500 0.8415137
[17,] 1000 0.8414281
```

Below is a graph of *standardized* chi-squared density curves for
degrees of freedom 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 500, and 1000 (in various rainbow
colors) along with the standard normal density (heavy black). At the resolution of the graph, the purple curve
for 1000 DF is hardly distinguishable from the black curve.

[image]

*Note:* Because none of your suggested answers seems correct, I'm wondering if the lower limit of the integral in your initial expression should have been $n + \sqrt{2n}$ (or the limits should have been $-\infty$ to $n - \sqrt{2n}).$
Notice that $1 - .1587 = .8413.$

Comment: Thank you and i am very sorry i didn't check original material it was copied question my tuition providers gave me. It was amisprint.

Comment: All is well, as long as you understand the convergence now. Just added a graph of standardized chi-sq densities converging to normal as DF increases.

Comment: Yes with your explanation and Henry's i am very much satisfied. I was very confused yesterday. Typing mistake wasted my lot of time.

Comment: And also my question on MLE is still pending could you check it out ?

Comment: Past my bedtime. Brain dead for now. Tomorrow if I can. And maybe someone smarter and more alert will give you a magnificent answer before then.

Comment: Okay goodnight. I will wait for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark.** The question is changed after posting this answer. The lower bound of the integral was $n-\sqrt[] {2n}$ first. The idea remains the same.

Your idea to use the Central Limit Theorem is good. First note that the sum of chi distributed random variables is again chi distributed.  Let $U_i\sim \chi_1^2$  i.i.d. then $\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\sim \chi_n^2 $. What you want to find is:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i>n-\sqrt[]{2n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}\int^\infty_{n-\sqrt[]{2n}}e^{-t/2}t^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\,dt
\end{align}
The LHS is:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i-n}{\sqrt[]{2n}}>-1\right)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i-n\mathbb E[U_1]}{\sqrt[]{n\operatorname{Var}(U_1)}}>-1\right)\\&\stackrel{CLT}{=} 1-\Phi(-1)
\end{align}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution. But $1-\Phi(-1)=\Phi(1)\approx 0.8413447$ which is not one of the options. Strange..

We conclude anyway that:

> \begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}\int^\infty_{n-\sqrt[]{2n}}e^{-t/2}t^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\,dt=\Phi(1)\approx 0.8413447
> \end{align}

Comment: You applied CLT same as i did but variance will be different.

Comment: @Damn1o1 I don't get it.. How will the variance  be different?

Comment: According to central limit theorem average converges to normal distribution not sum of random variables. Total number of observation will be there in the denominator of variance.

Comment: See henry comments i am just beginner .

Comment: @Damn1o1 I think I have applied it correctly. I have checked it numerically and it seems to be true. What Henry is talking about is (more or less) the same as what I am talking about.

Comment: It can be I am interpreting it wrong may be. But these were the options came in my previous years IIT JAM exam.

Comment: @Damn1o1 So you just picked some options which did not even belong to the exercise?

Comment: No options are right in front of you. Why would i do that , I am saying options can't be wrong.

Comment: @Damn1o1 then there must be some mistake in my elaboration. Let me know if you find it so that I can correct them!

Comment: What to do man ?

Comment: @Damn1o1 I don't know?

Comment: Thank you and i am very sorry i didn't check original material it was copied question my tuition providers gave me. It was a misprint.

Comment: @Damn1o1 its all fine as  long as you understand it.